# How to pause audio that was started elsewhere?

Tags: javascript

My audio is created within an object property's function, but I need to pause it from within a separate object property's function. Is there an easy way of doing this without restructuring my code?

```
let audio = {
  train: function() {
    let train = new Audio(
      "audio link"
    );
    train.play();
  }
}

let otherObject = {
   pauseAudio: function() {
   Audio.pause();
}
```

Comment: Not really. The `audio` object should be changed. Technically, you could monkeypatch `Audio` beforehand, but that's a *very* X solution to a Y problem. What exactly are your limits on "restructuring"?

Comment: Would be okay if I had to restructure, but it's a shame it can't be this neat. What would you recommend to make this work?

Answer (score 0):

The `train` element needs to be exposed outside of the `audio` object in order for other outside variables (like `otherObject`) to be able to see it, due to normal scoping rules. One possibility is for `audio` to have another property, a subobject whose properties point to the `Audio` instances:

```
const audio = {
  audioElements: {},
  train: function() {
    this.audioElements.train = new Audio(
      "audio link"
    );
    this.audioElements.train.play();
  }
}

const otherObject = {
  pauseAudio: function() {
    for (const audioElm of Object.values(audio.audioElements)) {
      audioElm.pause();
    }
  }
}
```

It's not clear if you really want to make separate audio elements every time `train` is called. If not, check to see if the property exists on the audio holder object first:

```
const audio = {
  audioElements: {},
  train: function() {
    if (!this.audioElements.train) {
      this.audioElements.train = new Audio(
        "audio link"
      );
    }
    this.audioElements.train.play();
  }
}

let otherObject = {
  pauseAudio: function() {
    for (const audioElm of Object.values(audio.audioElements)) {
      audioElm.pause();
    }
  }
}
```

This will be easily extensible to any number of audio elements / methods.